# How to add a class in dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have different drop-down list and i want to use the same style to be the same. One drop-down is been loaded dynamically.

```
@foreach (var x in Model)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-6">@x.Question</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @switch (x.QuestionTypeId)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    @Html.DropDownList("Question_" + @x.QuestionId, x.PossibleAnswers, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                }
                break; 
            }
```

I want to load the same style on the below drop-down as you can see; I got this error when i tried to run it

> Error: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2">Reviewer</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("Reviewer", "Select a Reviewer", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
    </div>
    <label class="col-md-2">Line of Business</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("LineOfBusiness", "Select a Value", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming `Reviewer` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` then its `@Html.DropDownList("Reviewer", null, "Select a Reviewer", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })` but none of this code will ever bind correctly to your model

Comment: `"Select a Reviewer"` must be replaced with `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here,

```
<div class="col-md-3">@Html.DropDownList("LineOfBusiness", "Select a Value", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })</div>
```

you pass "Select a Value" which is a `string`

insted of that

you have to pass `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` not `string`

in `@Html.DropDownList("Question_" + @x.QuestionId, x.PossibleAnswers, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })`

first check the type of `x.PossibleAnswers` and you will come to know what you missed.